# Short story in orient-style city, man abusing the children who teaches him to play an instrument, covered by his wife

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

I am looking for what I think is a short story that I read approximately 8-10 years ago. I read it in French, but I think it was a translation.

I vaguely remember that the story is set in a oriental-like city (with sand, desert, merchants, etc.).

In this story, a man (rich and powerful, or at least from a "noble" family) learns to play a string instrument (some kind of oud maybe?).

To this end, he pays a boy to teach him. At the end, the story goes along the lines of the boy going into the man's office, the man closing the door, and his wife making noises with the instrument, clearly suggesting that the man abuses the child and that she "pudically" covers for him by making noise so that the other people in the house would not have suspicions.

Any help would be appreciated!